# How to make autocomplete default to off for all input fields?

Tags: html

I am looking to set the default value of autocomplete to off for all input fields in my entire application. Then, for the fields where I want autocomplete I could do `autocomplete = "on"`for those fields only. I want autocomplete to be off much more often then on. I know I could go through each form/input in my application and set the autocomplete for each one, but that would be almost impossibly tedious.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far with sample expected scenarios

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using setAttribute and document.querySelectorAll('input') to get all input fields

1. Get all input fields using document.querySelectorAll (use class to turn off for specific fields)
2. Loop through using ForEach
3. Set Autocomplete to off for every input field

```js
function setNewAttr(){
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(v => {
    v.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
       console.log(v)
  }
  )
}

setNewAttr()
```

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="on">
<input type="text" autocomplete="on">
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PLdpbN?editors=1010